# Simplest possible Ubuntu GUI app

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, ubuntu

On Windows, no matter which framework you use, all the frameworks need, ultimately, to call the user mode user32::CreateWindowEx API to actually create a window on the desktop.

On Ubuntu, or indeed Linux systems in general, it seems that the choices are to use a widget framework like Wx or Qt or GTK+ to create a GUI application, but all these frameworks feel like they are wrapping something more fundamental. Do these all talk directly to X on Linux? I thought Ubuntu was moving to a non X window manager, so what are they going to use then?

What library would I use to access the window manager all these frameworks use?

Answer (score 5):

They are all wrapping [`Xlib`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib) , if you ever switch to non-X server you will need an `Xlib` replacement along with it (or an Xlib wrapper).

Comment: But this is still not the lowest one can fall, is it? I mean, one could create his own implementation of X client completely from ground up, without using Xlib or XCB or whatever, couldn't he? One could say that both Xlib and XCB are **also** wrappers - around the X protocol, that is. And if one truly wants to free oneself from all wrappers, one should start with building one's own version of the protocol. Am I mistaken here?

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin, indeed you can also go mad do this in assembly even.

Comment: So really, a new project now, should probably choose XCB over XLib?

Comment: @Chris Becke, Xlib is just a wrapper these days, but yes XCB is the way to go since its thread safe.

Comment: Realistically, don't choose between Xcb & Xlib, but use a higher-level toolkit (Qt4, Gtk3, ...).

Answer (score 1):

You could in principle write your own X library by learning the X11 protocol and all the related extensions (ICCCM, desktop conventions, ...) but that is a huge task. You would use the lowest level system calls (send, recv, ...) if you did that.

Some implementations of some languages (SML, Common Lisp, Ocaml) made that choice of implementing the X11 protocol without using the Xlib or XCB C libraries. But it is such a big task that I won't recommend it.

And the Wayland that Ubuntu speaks about is not mature yet, but the toolkit libraries (like GTK and Qt) are slowly moving to support it (in addition of supporting X11).

Today, you also have the option to develop Web based applications instead of X11 based ones. Sometimes HTTP + XHTML + AJAX is simpler that recoding an X11 thing from scratch.

But don't start alone the writing of a graphical stack... it is too big a task...

Comment: The simplest graphical user application is probably the hello world window on Qt or on GTK, but both Qt & GTK carries a lot of luggage, because the X11 protocol is big (it was designed for different hardware than the one we are using today!) and some people might question even its design (and its goal to support mechanism not policy). You don't need, as newbie, to care about the window manager. The Qt or Gtk toolkit will do that.

Answer (score 0):

X operates over a carefully specified network protocol, so you can speak this protocol directly to the server if you like. In practice, GUI toolkits wrap Xlib (and possibly Xt). Traditionally Xlib was as low as it went, but now Xlib has been reimplemented on top of a much cleaner low-level X protocol library "xcb".